# What are the reasons for passing a pointers to a shared_ptr to a function?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, apache-arrow

I was looking at the C++ API of Apache's Arrow library, and noticed that it is littered with member functions that take arguments of type `std::shared_ptr<T>*`. To me this looks unnecessarily contrived and possibly brittle, and it is frankly strange to me that a library would prescribe how I choose to solve the ownership of my instances of its classes. Thus my conclusion is that there must be some advantages to this approach that I am not aware of, which sparked my curiosity.

What are the advantages of functions that take pointers to smart pointers as arguments?

Herb Sutter does not mention this option in his article on [Smart Pointer Parameters](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/).

Comment: I pass them as references to avoid the copy overhead when calling a function that has no reason to be an owner, but I can't off the top of my head think of a good reason for a pointer.

Comment: Low info question. What are these functions doing? Do they change the `std::shared_ptr`? Are they IN/OUT or OUT parameters? Etc.

Comment: The only reason I can think of to pass via pointer (rather than via reference) would be if you wanted to be able to pass NULL to the function as some kind of special case (i.e. distinct from passing a NULL shared_ptr object).  I probably wouldn't do it in my code unless there was a really compelling reason for it, since it's kind of awkward for the caller to use.

Comment: @curiousguy Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: This discussion would be most appropriate on the project mailing list and not Stack Overflow: dev@arrow.apache.org

Comment: @WesMcKinney I don't see why. If it is an arraow sepcific quirk, there is no point in discussing it. If there is a good reason, more people could benefit from knowing about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr<…>*` is used in Arrow when a function is returning an object as a `shared_ptr` while at the same time the function may fail with one of `arrow::Status` codes.

Apache Arrow C++ adheres to the Google C++ style guide. One of the aspects is to [not use exceptions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Exceptions). Furthermore, normally output will be done with a normal `return` statement but in the cases where we also need to return a `Status`, we use the alternative approach of [returning it via a `non-const` pointer](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Output_Parameters).

For inputs where Arrow takes no ownership of the passed parameter, instead of `std::shared_ptr<T>`, functions take `const T&`. Shared pointers only appear in function signature if ownership is shared afterwards or when the parameter is **an output parameter**.

Comment: But you aren't returning via a non-`const` pointer to a type, you're returning via a non-`const` pointer to a non-`const` smart pointer to a type.

Comment: @masaers I suggest a further discussion on the development mailing list

Comment: @masaers There is difference between returning an object and a smart pointer sharing ownership to that object. In the second case, you can't know *a priori* whether there are other owners that might access the object; but you can check at runtime;

Comment: @curiousguy Yes. The question is not value vs. pointer, the question is pointer vs. pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: @curiousguy In the same way it's not a value vs value question. Sure pointers are values, but it is often useful to treat them as a special sort of values.